# How to test more than one thing after a lambda in rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, rspec

So I have something like this in Rails with rspec:

```
it "should create a new user" do
  lambda do
    post :create, @attr
  end.should change(User,:count)
end
```

But the post :create, @attr creates both a User and a Company, so how do I "chain" the *change* calls so that i can test both? 
What Im looking for is something like `end.should change(User,:count) && change(Company,:count)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd argue you're trying to assert to much in a single test and it doesn't match the name of the test. Consider this instead:

```
it "should create a new user" do
  lambda do
    post :create, @attr
  end.should change(User,:count)
end

it "should create a new company" do
  lambda do
    post :create, @attr
  end.should change(Company,:count)
end
```

Also, you may not be aware that there's a nicer way of writing those assertions which does the same thing, but reads much more nicely:

```
expect {
  post :create, @attr
}.to change(Company, :count)
```

Comment: Ooh, nice way to write it, gratz. After testing further and sleeping on it, I am inclined to agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

After growing as a developer for a couple of years, I have found quite a clean solution for testing multiple values when needed:

```
expect{ execute }.to change{ [spe1.reload.trashed?, spe2.reload.trashed?] }.from([true, true]).to([false, false])
```

But when we do need to test creation of multiple records:

```
[User, Company].each do |klass|
  it "creates one #{klass}" do
    expect{ post :create, valid_args }.to change(klass, :count).by(1)
  end
end
```

Comment: And the above should be wrapped in a context matching the business case

Answer (score 0):

@idlefingers - re:

> "I'd argue you're trying to assert to much in a single test and it
>   doesn't match the name of the test"

- Sometimes, though, I don't want another separate example just to perform another assertion, for performance reasons and to keep test suite time down.

To get around this, you can use this trick:

```
def user_and_company_count
  User.count + Company.count
end

it "can assert both counts" do
  expect { post :create, @attr }.to change(self, :article_an_activity_count).by(2)
end
```

Comment: Hey, thewoolleyman, thanks for the answer. While I still agree with idlefingers that my test was doing too much, I found a good way to test more than one thing at a time. See the 'multiple values' section: http://blog.houen.net/rspec-expect-change-record-value/